# Implement an Iterator in Rust for a struct with field HashSet

Tags: rust, iterator

I like to implement `Iterator` for the struct `FileSystem`:

```
pub struct FileSystem<'a> {
    file_system: HashSet<FileContent>,
    iter: hash_set::Iter<'a, FileContent>,
}

impl<'a> FileSystem<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> FileSystem<'a> {
        let file_system = HashSet::<FileContent>::new();
        let iter = file_system.iter();
        FileSystem { file_system, iter }
    }
}

impl<'a> Iterator for FileSystem<'a> {
    type Item = &'a FileContent;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.iter.next()
    }
}
```

Just to hide the `HashSet`-field `file_content`.

But all my trials failed.

In this particular case the compiler complains:

```
cannot return value referencing local variable `file_system`

let iter = file_system.iter()
           ----------- `file_system` is borrowed here
FileSystem { file_system, iter }
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

I somehow get this but have no clue how to link the iterators or how I can store the status of the iterator?

Comment: You almost certainly want two separate structs: one for the HashSet, and one that holds a reference to it and iterates over it.

Comment: Trying to put the `HashSet` and it's `.iter()` into the same struct is trying to create a self referential struct which is really hard in Rust due to ownership semantics, see [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct)

Comment: Do I want it because there is no other option? My aesthetics would rather go having all in one place like:   fs.add(...) and  for f in fs.

Comment: Ok  @cafce25 - I see the point now. Again and again I have to overcome my C-thinking. Thanks. Building a graph with pointer was also becoming a mess.

Comment: @BallpointBen: Avoiding self-references, stay simple and frugal with rust

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

pub struct FileSystem {
    file_system: HashSet<FileContent>,
}

impl FileSystem {
    pub fn new() -> FileSystem {
        let file_system = HashSet::<FileContent>::new();
        FileSystem { file_system }
    }

    pub fn iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &FileContent> {
        self.file_system.iter()
    }
}


fn main() {
    let fs = FileSystem::new();

    for file_content in fs.iter() {
        println!("{:?}", file_content);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could take it even further by implementing `Iterator` on `FileSystem` itself.